# How to insert sha256 hashed values into CnosDB?

Tags: cnosdb

I have same string values stores as a CSV.

```
time,json
2019-03-15T11:50:30,'{"func":"f5_u113","flag":"y"}'
2019-03-15T12:05:00,'{"func":"f3_u087","flag":"y"}'
2019-03-15T12:33:00,'{"func":"f7_u112","flag":"n"}'
2019-03-15T12:50:00,'{"func":"f5_u112","flag":"y"}'
```

I want to import these data to cnosdb, with an external hash column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE jfaq_tab(
    content STRING, -- stores CSV column 'json'
    hash STRING,    -- stores sha256 of CSV column 'json'
    TAGS(source),   -- stores sta
);
```

But I can't find the correct INSERT statement.

```sql
INSERT INTO jfaq_tab(time,source,content,hash) VALUES('2019-03-15T11:50:30', 'demo', '{"func":"f5_u113","flag":"y"}', SHA256('{"func":"f5_u113","flag":"y"}'));
-- Returns error:
-- Invalid argument error: Encountered non UTF-8 data: invalid utf-8 sequence of 1 bytes from index 1
```

Use `CASE` clause to do cast:

```sql
INSERT INTO jfaq_tab(time,source,content,hash) VALUES('2019-03-15T11:50:30', 'demo', '{"func":"f5_u113","flag":"y"}', CAST(SHA256('{"func":"f5_u113","flag":"y"}') AS STRING));
-- Returns error:
-- Optimizer rule 'simplify_expressions' failed
-- caused by: Arrow error: Invalid argument error: Encountered non UTF-8 data: invalid utf-8 sequence of 1 bytes from index 1
```

---

What can I do to get the converted sha256 hash into the database?